# How do I check what plugins are enabled via the database?

Tags: plugins, database

I'd like to query the database directly, and determine which plugins are enabled.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

### SQL

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

But for better approach will be the WordPress way:

### Wordpress

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
}

$active_plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
$all_plugins = get_plugins();
$activated_plugins = array();

foreach ($active_plugins as $plugin){           
    if(isset($all_plugins[$plugin])){
         array_push($activated_plugins, $all_plugins[$plugin]);
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that outputs the values in a human readable format:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u wordpress -p wordpress -ss --raw -N -e 'SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name="active_plugins"' | php -r "var_dump(unserialize(stream_get_contents(STDIN)));"
```

Comment: yeah it is stored in serialized format, so you had to unserialize it if directly accessing the database

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_options('active_plugins')` to retrieve all active plugins.

For checking against one plugin active or not you can use it like this :

```
if (in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) )) { 
   //Woocommerce Active
}
else{
   //Woocommerce Deactive
}
```

Comment: I'd like to query the database directly

Comment: it is located in wp_options table in field option_name = active_plugins